# Посоветуйте расширения VSCode для Go

Tags: golang, visual-studio-code

Решил попробовать Go. За неимением IDE для Go, решил использовать Visual Studio Code. До этого никогда им не пользовался.

Встал вопрос, какими средствами возможно максимально удобно настроить среду разработки? Возможно ли сделать компиляцию и запуск проекта по нажатию горячей клавиши и/или кнопки в самом VSCode? Какие существуют удобные расширения для этого?

Comment: а как же https://www.jetbrains.com/go/

Comment: @NikitaUmnov, никогда не слышал, ноэто по вроде исключительно платное, не вижу комьюнити версии

Comment: Есть месяц триала, попробовать хватит, и не тратить нервы на настройку для знакомства с новым языком. А там станет ясно, что вам нужно от IDE. А вообще продукты от JetBrains стоящие, хоть и прожорливые

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Возможно ли сделать компиляцию и запуск проекта по нажатию горячей клавиши и/или кнопки в самом VSCode?

Возможно. [Официальное расширение](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.Go) от Microsoft уже включает все необходимое.